# How to use EasyMock In unitTest

Tags: unit-testing, testing, easymock

I am new to EasyMock in unitTest.

I have a case like this:

```
EasyMock.expect(serviceUnderTest.functionABC(param)).andReturn("123");
EasyMock.replay(contantsUnderTest);
```

This only works for the specific param; how can I implement it so that no matter what param is input, if the **functionABC** in **serviceUnderTest** is called, it will return 123?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use one of EasyMock's matchers.

```
EasyMock
  .expect(
    serviceUnderTest.functionABC(EasyMock.anyObject(TypeOfParameter.class)))
  .andReturn("123");
```

For more details have a look at [EasyMock's Javadoc](http://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/EasyMock.html).

Comment: yeah, sure. By the way, would you mind take a look to this issue?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32560348/how-to-make-the-non-mocked-function-run-in-normal-behavior